# PHP pipe to script email

Tags: php, email

I am trying to forward all emails from support@example.com to PHP script to be inserted into MySql.

My script works, but I have two issues.

1. The from email address shows the name of the sender, not the email address.
2. The email body content shows for eg.

   --00000000000095430105a9347fe3
   Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

This is a test email

--00000000000095430105a9347fe3
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

This is a test email

--00000000000095430105a9347fe3--

Instead of just the body of the email *This is a test email*

This is my code:

```
// handle email
 $lines = explode("\n", $email);

 // empty vars
 $from = "";
 $subject = "";
 $headers = "";
 $message = "";
 $splittingheaders = true;
 for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
 if ($splittingheaders) {
    // this is a header
    $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";


    // look out for special headers
    if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
        $subject = $matches[1];
    }
    if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
        $from = $matches[1];
    }
    if (preg_match("/^To: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
        $to = $matches[1];
    }
    } else {
        // content/main message body information
        $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
  
    }

    if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
    // empty line, header section has ended
    $splittingheaders = false;
    }
}
```

I have tried

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($mbox,1,'1');

$message = strip_tags(quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($mbox,1,"1")));
$message = strip_tags($message, '<body>');
$message = explode(">", $message);
$message = explode("<", $message[1]);
$message = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $message[0]);
$message = html_entity_decode($message);
$message = trim($message);
```

And I tried this but could not figure out how to make it work:

```
   $emailnumberPattern = "--[0]{12}";
   $replacement = " ";
   preg_replace($emailnumberPattern, $replacement, $string);
   $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
```

Any help would be welcome to show the sender email as well as remove unwanted content from the email body.

Comment: I tested yout code, and `$from` correctly contains `First Last <first.last@company.org>`.

Comment: Thanks. My issue is that when I reply from my support panel, it does not recognize the email format `First Last <first.last@company.org>`. So I would like to remove `First Last` and only wants `first.last@company.org`

Comment: That's easily solvable: `if (preg_match('/ <(.*)>/', $from, $matches)){$from = $matches[1];}`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks I will change that now. Can you help me to solve the issue to remove --00000000000095430105a9347fe3 Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

--00000000000095430105a9347fe3 Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"


--00000000000095430105a9347fe3--. So that only the message is inserted, in this case This is a test email

Comment: @simlev I have tried `$messages .= $lines[$i]."\n";
            $message = preg_replace('/Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
/',' ',$messages);` without success Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing emails is no easy task that can be solved with a couple of regexes. You should definitely use a dedicated [extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php) or [program](https://pldaniels.com/ripmime). Also, you shold avoid loading the entire message into a single string (or array).

[This one](https://github.com/zbateson/mail-mime-parser) is just a single [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) command away: `composer require zbateson/mail-mime-parser`.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$handle = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$message = \ZBateson\MailMimeParser\Message::from($handle);
fclose($handle);
$from = $message->getHeaderValue('from');
$body = $message->getTextContent();
```

---

That said, you can obtain *some* results with your code, which I've modified as little as possible:

```
 $lines = explode("\n", $email);

 // empty vars
 $from = "";
 $subject = "";
 $headers = "";
 $message = "";
 $splittingheaders = true;
 for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
 if ($splittingheaders) {
    // this is a header
    $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";


    // look out for special headers
    if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
        $subject = $matches[1];
    }
    if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
        $from = $matches[1];
    }
    if (preg_match("/^To: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
        $to = $matches[1];
    }
    } else {
        if (preg_match('/Content-Type: text\/plain; charset=/', $lines[$i])) {
            $m = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (preg_match('/Content-Type:/', $lines[$i])) {
            $m = false;
        }
        if ($m) {
            $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
        }
    }

    if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
    // empty line, header section has ended
    $splittingheaders = false;
    }
 }
 if (preg_match('/ <(.*)>/', $from, $matches)){
     $from = $matches[1];
 }
```

Those results are not guaranteed, and highly dependent on the input format. For a robust solution, please use a well-tested parser.

Comment: I'd replace `for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++)` with `foreach($lines as $line)` then use `$line` in place of `$lines[$i]` (could also replace the three regexs with `preg_match('/^(Subject|To|From): (.*)/', $lines, $match);
${strtolower($match[1])} = $match[2];` but variable variables :/)